# OR Operator used in parenthesis along with where clause returns different result.

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

What is the difference between the below two SQL statements:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE Country='France' OR Country='Mexico'
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE (Country='France' OR Country='Mexico')
```

Why do these two statements return different results?

Comment: There is no difference between these two statements. Can you share the results with us? Is the query you are showing us the entire statement you are using or are there different `WHERE` clauses involved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference.

```
declare @t table (id int identity (1,1), country varchar(20), b int)

insert @t (country, b) values ('france',1),('france',2),('france',3),('mexico',1),('mexico',4), ('brazil',1)

select * from @t where (country = 'france' or country = 'mexico') 
select * from @t where country = 'france' or country = 'mexico'
-- both return rows 1-5
```

*However*, if you add a further clause (eg `AND`) then you need to consider which clauses take priority.

```
select * from @t 
where (country = 'france' or country = 'mexico') and b = 1

-- returns  rows 1 and 4

select * from @t 
where country = 'france' or country = 'mexico'  and b = 1

-- returns rows 1-4
```

Comment: if I add a further AND clause then why do these two statements return different results?

Comment: Because AND takes priority. Much like in maths, where x takes priority over +

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in this query and this two queries should return the same results - i've event tested this. It's for sure. SQL where clouse works according to logic laws:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_logic#Basic_and_derived_argument_forms

So the brackets in this case do nothing.